# VIM - Auto-indent lines with over length

Tags: vim, macvim, indentation, autoindent

Is there an option in VIM to auto-intend (like in Espresso) lines which are too long to be displayed in the current window so that they get an automatic line break?

This is how it looks like in Espresso:

[image: Espresso auto-indent]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your wrapped lines to not go completely to the left but instead respect indentation, right?

I don't think there is a way to do that. Sorry.

Comment: That's just what I meant. Is there really no way to enable a behavior like that in VIM?

Comment: I'm using Vim fulltime since 1 year only. There are people around here with a lot more experience than me so don't consider my "no" as definitive. However I don't see anything in the docs that would help you do that. Beside actually formating your code in an old-school but sane way: 80 columns max.

Answer (score 1):

In Normal mode, type

```
:set wrap
```

so that long lines are wrapped. This doesn't add a '\n' newline, or any indent, it just moves it to a new screen line.

Or,

```
:set textwidth=78
gggqG
```

to reformat an entire document to fit within a certain line width. (It does this automatically for new lines typed, and you can also use `gqap` to format a single paragraph.

Comment: +1 Because it is a really good tip for someone who may come to this question and looking just for this command. But it's not what I meant.